# Explanation on the tkinter layout settings to use to position to buttons side by side properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

For the first time, I need to use tkinter for a very small and simple GUI. I am trying to create a window with 2 buttons placed side by side. If I was to use matplotlib widgets, I would do:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 2))

# Start button
start_button_ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.6])
start_button = Button(start_button_ax, 'Start MML', color='lightgoldenrodyellow', hovercolor='0.975')
def start_button_on_clicked(mouse_event):
    pass
start_button.on_clicked(start_button_on_clicked)

# Stop button
stop_button_ax = fig.add_axes([0.6, 0.2, 0.3, 0.6])
stop_button = Button(stop_button_ax, 'Stop MML', color='lightgoldenrodyellow', hovercolor='0.975')
def stop_button_on_clicked(mouse_event):
    pass
stop_button.on_clicked(stop_button_on_clicked)
```

Result:

[image: Matplotlib GUI]

Very simple stuff. With tkinter, I have been struggling for the past hour trying to move around and resize the 2 buttons. Here is my current code:

```
import tkinter as tk

def start():
    global running
    running = True

def stop():
    global running
    running = False
    
windowWidth = 200
windowHeight = 100
    
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Minimum Masking Level")
root.geometry(f'{windowWidth}x{windowHeight}+{int(root.winfo_screenwidth()/2 - windowWidth/2)}+{int(root.winfo_screenheight()/3 - windowHeight/2)}')

start = tk.Button(root, text="Start counting", command=start)
start.place(x=20, y=20)
stop = tk.Button(root, text="Stop counting", command=stop)
stop.place(x=110, y=20)
root.mainloop()
```

I tried using `.config(width=, height=)` to resize the button.. but that was clearly not the way to go. Could someone help me produce the desired output and explain a bit how the Tkinter coordinate system/positioning/resizing of widgets work?

Edit following comments: Trying to add width and height at the creation of the button:

```
start = tk.Button(root, text="Start counting", command=start, width=70, height=60)
start.place(x=20, y=20)
```

Output:

[image: bad output]

Yet the window should have a width of 200 and height of 100. 20 + 70 should easily fit.

Comment: If you switch from using `.place` to `.pack`, you can specify `expand=True, fill="both"`

Comment: `grid()` is very useful in this. What is wrong with the code you have.

Comment: @CoolCloud The positionmning and the size of the button is wrong. I did try to use grid a bit. IThen the .place() was not working anymore. I am looking to produce a similar output as the one with matplotlib, i.e. button placed at 0.1 and 0.6 of the frame, width 0.3, height 0.6 with equal 0.2 spacing at the top and bottom.

Comment: @TheLizzard Can not even make it work.. so I have no clue what those 2 additional parameters would do.

Comment: Well what you should be doing is, get the width of widget and add it to the `x`

Comment: @CoolCloud As I wrote, I tried to change the width of widget with .config. It didn't work out. Is it too much to ask to actually be able to specify a desired x/y/width/height as in matplotlib or opencv?

Comment: While defining button, you can add an option as argument, `width=50` or whatever, that would just shorten the button, to not fix the text.

Comment: @CoolCloud Tried it too. For this one I edited my question with a screenshot of the result. Obviously not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def start():
    global running
    running = True

def stop():
    global running
    running = False
    
windowWidth = 200
windowHeight = 100
    
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Minimum Masking Level")
root.geometry(f'{windowWidth}x{windowHeight}+{int(root.winfo_screenwidth()/2 - windowWidth/2)}+{int(root.winfo_screenheight()/3 - windowHeight/2)}')

start = tk.Button(root, text="Start counting", command=start)
start.pack(expand=True, fill="both", padx=5, pady=10, side="left")
stop = tk.Button(root, text="Stop counting", command=stop, width=50, height=2)
stop.pack(expand=True, fill="both", padx=5, pady=10, side="right")
root.mainloop()
```

Also try changing the values for `padx`/`pady`. The documentation is [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20201111222645/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm). You can change the size of the text inside the button by putting `font=("", <size as in>)` inside the button definition.

Comment: That's a lot better. Thank you!

Comment: Why does the second button, stop, has parameter width and height; while the first one doesn't? How does this make sense?

Comment: @Mathieu To show you that you can still declare the width/height of the buttons. You can remove it if you want. It should change the layout that much.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here, because using `grid()` is more accurate, because if you have more than one widget, it will get hard to understand what to do. With `grid` its just rows and columns:

```
start_b = tk.Button(root, text="Start counting",command=start)
start_b.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=20)

stop_b = tk.Button(root, text="Stop counting", command=stop)
stop_b.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=20)
```

If you are wondering why some of the button is cut out, it is because you are setting your own `geometry` to window and it is smaller than that of the buttons. Anyway notice that I renamed your buttons to not be as same as the function name, as it might cause issues later. `padx` adds some space to both the sides along x axis to the widget. Similary, there is `pady` too. Also there is `ipady` and `ipadx` which is to give space inside the widget or make it grow in size.